# SQL Server: using the result from an operation twice in the select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I was wondering what is the best way to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    num1 - num2 as 'Substraction'
    IIF(num1 - num2 > 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS 'num1IsBigger'
FROM
    numbers
```

I don't want to repeat `(num1 - num2)` twice, since you can't do this:

```
SELECT 
    num1 - num2 as 'Substraction'
    IIF(Substraction > 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS 'num1IsBigger'
FROM
    numbers
```

I can think of a few ways to solve it, but none of them seem straight forward or "optimal", so what is the best way to solve it?

Comment: Keep it as it is.

Comment: The usual way is a CTE: `WITH n AS (SELECT x = num1 - num2 FROM Numbers) SELECT ... FROM n`. For a simple expression like this it's overkill; you'd probably just pay the T-SQL tax and copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use common table expression

```
with cte as
(
SELECT 
    num1 - num2 as 'Substraction'
    FROM
    numbers
)
select IIF(Substraction > 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS 'num1IsBigger' from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it in sub-query first, then use it in select, like this :

```
SELECT 
    Diff as 'Substraction'
    IIF(Diff > 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS 'num1IsBigger'
FROM
    (select num1,num2,num1-num2 Diff numbers) AS n
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is a CTE or subquery, but I like using lateral joins (i.e., the `APPLY` keyword).  I would write this as:

```
SELECT v.Substraction,
       (CASE WHEN substraction > 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS num1IsBigger
FROM numbers CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (num1 - num2)) v(subtraction);
```

Notes:

- I replaced the bespoke function with `IIF()` with the standard `CASE` expression.  The latter is not only standard, but it is more flexible and available in basically all databases.
- I removed the single quotes around column aliases.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants -- and column names should not require escaping.
- Lateral joins are super-powerful, and a simple example like this is a good way to get introduced to them.